# need help on font rendering from website to safari, preview and adobe

Tags: mac, safari, pdf, preview, font

I am on an iMac with high Sierra 10.13.6.  Have been having this issue over multiple os for a long time.  When i go to my financial website and view A monthly statement I n safari pop up, the font is hard to read and too close.  Same in Adobe reader when opened in the downloaded .pdf.  If I do the same in Firefox it looks good until I download it then its too close again.  No issues on a pc.  ive tried to change the screen resolution with no effect.  also checked the Mac fonts and all seem to be good - no corruption.  any ideas on what to check.  the attached is a small sample of adobe / safari too close together and what I would expect and like to see form firefox.  Still troubleshooting this one. Spent another hour on the phone with the bank - no luck. Have now discovered that while the file can be viewed ok with Firefox, I get the messed up fonts when printing from there.  Also have tried to export from Firefox as .pdf file with no luck either - then the fonts stagger between small-normal to oversized. Still trying to figure it out. 
[image: firefox example what I expect to see]
[image: safari/adobe/preview problem]

Comment: Not to be snarky, but a web site really has to work hard to mess up fonts when viewed by iOS or macOS. Can you get a different site that at least can work in plain text? If they can’t generate a usable PDF, fire them.

Comment: I only have the problem with Morgan Stanley.  And it works ok on a pc.

Comment: And they can’t tell you exactly what fonts you need to have to make their reports render correctly? Have you printed one and mailed it to them asking for help? That way their business manager knows their support isn’t helping. Unless you have zero money with them, I can’t imagine they don’t know exactly how to make you happy. You’d need to upload a PDF here for use to have a chance to help you out.

Comment: man, ive worked hours with them and some time with apple who says its not their problem.  Ive sent MS screen shots, files and even upgraded my Adobe to the cloud based version which I did not want to do.  I even converted a .pdf file to text to they could see the coding and font info.  Its BS.  I have about 35 email going back and forth.

Comment: its something to do with the website I believe and how it treats their reports retrieved via a weblink. I can read all the reports they create or email to me, just now the statements I get online.

Comment: Perfect, why not simplify about 3/4 of the post. Just plain and simple - downloaded reports work, screen ones don’t. The only problem is you might not want to share the actual PDF due to financial or privacy issues.

Comment: Edited for clarity - sorry.....  the reports they send from time to time are .pdf progress reports. The problems I am having are with monthly statements on/from their website. I’d like to stay paperless so I don’t have reams of paper to keep.

Comment: +1 for the edits. If I have any ideas I’ll put up an answer even if it’s incomplete. Maybe it will help another get you closer to a solution.